Participle clauses - different subjects
Are these sentences correct?

This study was done using the method proposed by X.
This formula should be simplified keeping in mind that the parameter C is positive.

Such constructions often appear in scientific papers. However, I am afraid of using them because the subjects in the main clause and in the participle clause are not the same. Can anybody explain this grammatical issue to me?

done implies a doer of an action, and to do things often requires   an implement of some kind (a knife, a rake, a centrifuge), or a method, hence the implicit doer will be using  it.   simplified is a particular kind of action, again with an implicit simplifier, the one who simplifies, and that implicit actor is sentient and can keep something in mind while taking the action, hence keeping in mind.    So it is the implications of those past participles(done,simplified), their underlying verbs, that admit certain participial clauses and exclude others.

Consider a book of rules of a religious sect that require a person to be shunned when they commit some transgression. "The person must be shunned, using...".    Does shunning someone require a tool or implement or detailed method?  No.  So a participial clause introduced by using would thus not make sense there.  But it might involve some kind of special effort: "The person should be shunned, taking care never to look them in eye and never to take something from their hand."    The shunner should take care not to look the person in the eye and not to have any contact with them.

Rather than asking if the sentences are correct, which looks like a request for proofreading (and requests for proofreading are not allowed). It would be better to start your post with simply the two examples.

What causes you concern about the clauses’ having different subjects? Consider I thought she liked ice cream.

Both sentences are fine, although sentence 2 should have a comma.
There's no requirement that the participle clause should refer to the subject of the main clause. Example 1 is parsed as:

This study was done using [the method proposed by X].

"proposed by X" is a qualifier that identifies "the method".
In sentence 2, you should add a comma before "keeping in mind". This clause then qualifies how you perform the action described in the main clause.
